# How to solve this query,in java query mongo collection

Tags: java, mongodb

mongo data example :[mongo data example :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppD0X.png)

```
    Document query1 = doc("project", "projectId")
            .append("student", "studentId")
            .append("target", new Document().append("id","001").append("name","subject"));

    Document query2 = doc("project", "projectId")
            .append("student", "studentId")
            .append("target", new Document().append("name","subject").append("id","001"));

    db.getCollection("collection").find(query1)  //result is not null
    db.getCollection("collection").find(query2)  //result is null
```

why?

Comment: Read [Query on Embedded/Nested Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/) in the core documentation. `"target": { "id": "001", "name": "subject" }` is different to `"target": { "name": "subject", "id": "001" }` because of the order. But querying `{ "target.name": "subject", "target.id": "001" }` does not care which order.

Comment: Why not post this as an answer?